# gms:play-services-ads version 19.7.0 has been reported as problematic by its author and will block publishing of your app to Play Console

Tags: android, admob

My Android App Is Remove by Google play
App removed :- App removed from Google Play

The SDK developer com.google.android.gms has added a note for play-services-ads:19.7.0. Here's what the SDK developer told us:

This version is scheduled to sunset on June 30th 2023. See https://developers.google.com/admob/android/deprecation for more information.

If you do not upgrade to a newer version, you may not be able to release future versions of your app with this SDK.

com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads version 19.7.0 has been reported as problematic by its author and will block publishing of your app to Play Console

Comment: Are you able to still publish an app update? If so, just update the Ads dependency & release an updated apk.

Answer (score 1):

Update the Google Mobile Ads SDK to the latest version.
You can do this by opening your project's `build.gradle` file and changing the version of the SDK to the latest version:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:22.3.0'
}
```